# Python and solve_ivp: output internal data from ode-function

Tags: python, scipy, ode

To solve a system of ODEs, I need internal calculations of past time steps, so I have to save these internal calculations. I cannot save every calculation because of dynamic time step size of the solver.
The event function doesn't help me either, because events only receives (t, y) input, but my internal data is a function of (t,y), f(t, y).

Is there an elegant solution to save internal parameters when the solver has calculated a solution and not an internal calculation?

The Problem is a system of ordinary ODEs.

dydt = f(y, P) with P = f(y, e) and  e = f(P(t), P(t-1))

What I need is (I think) a simple way to save P in order to access the value of the last time step P(t-1), while P is not a sulution of integrating dydt.

Comment: Is your equation actually an ODE (unlikely, you would not try to implement some memory) or is it actually a delay-differential equation, DDE? There are DDE solvers in other packages like Sundials or Jitcode/Jitcdde. Could you give a simplified example of your system, in mathematical formulas and code?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I just updated the problem. My problem is a system of ordinary ODEs, but the code of the problem is still that big, that it's hard to show it as example...

Comment: No, taking values at time `t-1` removes this from the class of ODE and makes it a DDE with all the complications this entails. In a solver you would need that the time step is sufficiently small and use a sufficiently accurate interpolation of the previous solution to keep the error order of the solver. Hacking a standard solver is notoriously difficult, you might get along by using the stepper classes directly and fashioning the main time loop yourself. Or use DDE solver, apparently there is also a package `ddeint` available via `pip`.

Comment: It appears that your equations are circular, especially concerning `P(t)`? Or do the different `f` and `P` mean different functions in different places?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick and detailed answer! f and P are different functions in different places, so e is a function of P(t) and P(t-1). P(t-1) is used for a controller, which is calculating a controller-output like e = [P(t) - P(t-1)] / dt (like a common PID-controller).